# Combine categories in spotfire pie chart

Tags: pie-chart, spotfire

I am new to spotfire. I have a variable with many categories. I want to plot piechart for it. All categories which having contribution less than 5% will show together as "Other" in piechart. Can we do this in spotfire?

Answer (score 0):

You need a calculated column where you insert "Other" for the appropriate rows, like:

`if((sum([value column]) over ([category column]))/sum([value column])<0.05,"Other",[category column])`

Answer (score 0):

You can 'mark' the segments you want, right-click and 'Group from Marked Categories'. Then name them 'Other'.

This will automatically create a new binned column which you can maintain in Edit>Column Properties.